# From: jquery multiple select option dependent

Tags: jquery, forms

I know how to setup jquery so that if one select option is chosen, then options within another select can be disabled: e.g.

```
$("#div1").change(function(){  
if ($(this).val() == "100" ) {
$("#div2 option[value='200']").attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

but I am having trouble taking this to the next stage so that if Select1>option1  AND Select2>option 3 are chosen THEN select3 should disable certain options.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement two .change() functions and in each of those you check the value of the current select AND the value of the other one

```
$('#div1').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == "100" && $('#div2').val() == "200") {
      ...
   }
});

$('#div2').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == "200" && $('#div1').val() == "100") {
      ...
   }
});
```

Comment: yup it works, that was a lot simpler than I thought. I was working on trying to find a way which didn't require two change functions but this works just fine thank you :)