# jquery select option && NOT an option of a separate select

Tags: jquery, select

MY original question was here: [From: jquery multiple select option dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776201/from-jquery-multiple-select-option-dependent)

But I'm trying to work out, on a complex from which has lots of dependent selects, how to essentially say if this select option is chosen and NOT a specific option from another select then do this...

here are some things I've tried poorly and failed with:

```
if($(this).val() == "10000" && $("#someselect option:not([value='800']) {
```

or

```
if($(this).val() == "10000" && $("#someselect").not('[val="800"]')) {
```

Comment: `$("#someselect").not('[val="800"]')` haven't you forgotten any comparison here?

Answer (score 1):

`$("#someselect").not('[val="800"]')` is going to give you back an object reference, not a value.

Answer (score 1):

try simply

```
if($(this).val() == "10000" && $("#someselect").val() != "800" ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ( $(this).val() === "10000" && $("#someselect").val() !== "800" ) {
   //your work here
}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, works perfectly. I'm sure I tried this and it didn't work so it must have been a typo, thank you again for the quick reply

Comment: I think all of us here had the same idea, eno :) glad it helped. Just a quick note: use `===` instead of `==` wherever possible in javascript...it will save you some headaches!

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
if($(this).val() == "10000" && $("#someselect option:selected").val()!='800') {
    //do stuff//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly then you are trying to do something if the value of the current element (`this`) is something, and the value of another element is not something, then continue. If that's right, then you can use `val` to get the value of the second element too:

```
if($(this).val() === "10000" && $("#someselect").val() !== "800") {
    //Continue
}
```

The `:not` selector and `.not` method are used to exclude elements from the matched set, which is not at all what you are looking for.

Comment: blimey three comments in a minute all spot on. Thank you again. I'm sure I tried this and it failed but it must have been a typo and then I walked down a wrong avenue in desperation! :)